# android emulator in android studio is too slow and can't use it fully

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator

Android studio is too slow and I am not able to use back, home, option keys.
And I am also not able to rotate emulator.How can I improve the performance of the emulator and can use the all keys and rotation feature???

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements refer the system requirement. It's all you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Genymotion too.

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/

It runs using Virtual Box. Should be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

For the speed, it is kind've dependent on your system specs, but give this a try  http://jolicode.com/blog/speed-up-your-android-emulator

As for rotation, try these:

Mac: ctrl + fn + f12

Windows: left ctrl + f12

Linux: ctrl + f12

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio and Emulator are different tools. You can use each other independent of one another.

Emulator is slow and most of the times unusable. See a post by Jake Wharton on emulators [Android needs a simulator](http://jakewharton.com/android-needs-a-simulator/.).

For the time being you can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) or use your own device to debug.